# File Storeage Using Kinvey Rest api

Tags: rest, file-storage, kinvey

I try to upload image using KINVEY REST api (http://devcenter.kinvey.com/rest/guides/files#Uploading)

but i failed to upload file in file storage.

please tell me how to send image file-name/file-data  in get/put request and 
which header should i use.

also refer any link which help me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an engineer at Kinvey.  To use the REST API, you need to first get an API URL to upload by making a GET request to:

```
/blob/:appKey/upload-loc/:fileName
```

That will return a response with the following object:

```
{ "URI" : <externalLocation> }
```

Exctract response.body.URI, and perform a PUT request to that URI.  Set the content-length header, and pass your binary file as the request.body.

A couple of notes about file upload:

- The URI retrieved by upload-loc is only valid for 30 seconds
- The library only supports files < 64 MB in size.

Comment: thanks mjsalinger, but it will really helpful if you give me a sample of PUT request specially request body part.

Comment: can you tell me how to send file data in request body 
my data is like 
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAYEB.....

Comment: setting the content-length header causes problems in many browsers. Can you provide some info on that ?